# Dynamically showing the people who come online / offline

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been working on a project that is supposed to be a forum but i got stuck. i want to show all the online / offline players dinamically without needing to restart the page to see who comes online or who goes offline

I have tried with automatic page refresh but that isnt aesthetically pleasing and it might cause me problems in the future, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery post is an option and so is socket.io